# Finding the highest pair in int array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a dice game, where I need to find the highest pair of 5 dices and get the total of it. 
I have made this code so far which counts the numbers into pairs. Now I want to find the highest pair.

Code:

```
int Pair[];
Pair = new int[7] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} //Seven pairs because i dont want to use Pair[0]

int TT[];
TT = new int[5] { 1, 6, 3, 1, 3 }; //five dice

int t = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if ( TT[i] == t)
    {
    Pair[t] = Pair[t] + 1;
    t = t + 1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the highest pair? Is it the sum of the numbers or something else? If this is the case, all you really need to do is sort the list of integers, and take the two largest.

Comment: Or may it be the number that occurs at least twice? `3` in the example above.

Comment: I didn't think of that initially - edited my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you are overcomplicating it. If you think about it, what you want are the two highest numbers from an arry. Simply sort it, and reverse it, and take the two first numbers.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] Dice = new int[5] { 1, 6, 3, 1, 3 };
        Array.Sort(Dice);
        Array.Reverse(Dice);
        Console.WriteLine("The largest pair is ({0}, {1})", Dice[0], Dice[1]);
    }
}
```

The other possibility for the largets pair (as mentioned in a comment) is that you want to find the highest number in the list that occurs twice. You can do this by sorting the Array, reversing it, so you read from the highest number. Then incrementally check if the current number matches the next number, and if this is the case, you found the highest pair.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] Dice = new int[5] { 1, 6, 3, 1, 3 };
        Array.Sort(Dice);
        Array.Reverse(Dice);

        for (int i = 1; i < Dice.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Dice[i] == Dice[i - 1])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The largest pair is ({0}, {1})", Dice[i], Dice[i-1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While these approaches are good enough for this tiny example, you should in general take care of writing efficient code. E.g. the calls to `Array.Reverse()` are superfluous and just consume valuable time without giving you anything (except the convenient indexing). Both problems can be solved without sorting (which takes at least `O(n log n)`) in linear time. Althogh it is questionable, if the linear-time approaches are actually faster than the sorting approach for this tiny example.

Comment: It's possible to solve the problem without sorting yes, but the solution is much more complicated, and I think this is an entry level question, where performance is not really an issue, which is also why I added the Reverse operation. I know it's the most efficient version, but it's clear and easy to understand. Also O(n log n) is not much slower than O(n), unless the size of the input is huge. :)

Comment: This was much easier. Thanks for the answer.

I also need to detect if there is a pair in the array. Is there a short code to detect dublicates in an array?

Comment: This is what the second paragraph does - it checks if there are two identical integers in the array.